# Can i read PDF header and footer and set it into new one PDF in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where need to `read pdf header and footer` of existing and `create new with that header and footer.`

Which `gem` is best one for it in Rails and how to do it.

Any one have idea.

Thanks

Comment: Even though you are developing a Rails app, your task is not specific to Rails. Look for a general PDF gem and use it in your Rails workers. Basically, look at it as a general ruby code. For a [list of gems see this page](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation).

Comment: One gem I've worked with is rika, which is a Ruby wrapper around the Tika Apache Java library.  Using it would require running in JRuby, and Tika only parses documents, it does not create them.  Even if this is not workable for you, you might find better libraries in Javaland than Rubyland, and you can easily call them with JRuby.